# PHP 5.6 SESSION handling (writing, reading)

Tags: php, session, php-5.6

Im getting this notice on my executing website:

`Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in *PATH* on line 25` which is this line of code `$_SESSION["Registration_Error"] = TRUE;` why is the $_SESSION-Variable unkown?

Do they changed the way one can save data in the Session-Variable/Cookie?

Haven't found something good on Google. Just this http://php.net/manual/de/book.session.php#116217 and I dont think that this helps much.

Ideas?

EDIT:

Full Code

```
<?php

session_start();

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include "../backend/classes/$class_name.php";
}

$Connection = new DB_Connect();
$User_Functions = new User_Functions();

$UserName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "UserName");
$Password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Password");
$Mail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "Mail");
$date = new DateTime();
$Registration_Date = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if (!empty($UserName) && !empty($Password) && !empty($Mail)) {
    if (!$User_Functions->User_Exists($UserName)) {
        $Password_hashed = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $Query = "INSERT INTO wordsusers (`wordsUserName`, `wordsUserPassword`, `wordsUserMail`, `wordsUserRegDate`) VALUES (:wordsUserName, :wordsUserPassword, :wordsUserMail, :wordsUserRegDate)";
        $Parameter = array(":wordsUserName" => $UserName, ":wordsUserPassword" => $Password_hashed, ":wordsUserMail" => $Mail, ":wordsUserRegDate" => $Registration_Date);
        $Registered = $Connection->Execute_PDO_Command($Query, $Parameter);
    } else {
        $_SESSION["Registration_Error"] = TRUE;
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: yes at the first line ;)

Comment: There's no way they would make such a drastic, incompatible change without years of warning. You must have a typo or something in your script.

Comment: Are you getting the `Headers already sent` warning?

Comment: Where is the `<?php` line? Is there anything before that? Even a blank line will break things.

Comment: netbeans automatically creates blank lines and thats not the solution

Comment: Actually, a blank line doesn't cause that error. I get the "headers already sent", but `session_start` still initializes `$_SESSION` to an empty array.

Comment: yeah. but why do I get this error?

Comment: When I google the error, I find 3 causes: Missing `session_start()`, not using all uppercase `SESSION`, and something about Drupal login pages. I can't think of any reason why it's not working for you, this is an incredibly basic feature of PHP.

Comment: okay, im not using drupal so trying to go back to 5.5 where it should work :P

Comment: @Barmar same error -.-

Comment: I doubt it's a 5.6 thing, maybe something changed in your `php.ini` when you upgraded.

Comment: got ini-files for 5.3 5.4 5.5 5.6 and currently im using 5.5 and the specific ini-file

Comment: Check your script with a hex editor, make sure there are no extraneous, invisible characters in it.

Comment: like Notepad++? @Bamar doesn't found something

Comment: I don't know Notepad++. I'd use `hexl-find-file` in Emacs.

Comment: are you using file session handler? could you get the output `ini_get('session.save_path')` and see If any session files are created?

Comment: okay error disappeared without any sound. cool story brah -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allow all users to read and write to the directory. Fix the ownership and permissions so that www-data can both read and write (rwx). For instance:

chgrp www-data /var/lib/php5/sessions

chmod g+rwx /var/lib/php5/sessions

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental features and purposes of the $_SESSION, has not changed across the PHP versions after it deprecated $HTTP_SESSION_VARS in version 4, it's still properly maintained, persistent across pages and a Super Global variable.
However its more fault tolerant in the lower versions of PHP, from 5.4 downward than from 5.5 upwards with 5.6 inclusive.

General rule, do not output anything before calling the session_start() functions, which initiates the creation of the session variable or re-initiation of the existing session variable.

However, the lower versions of PHP can tolerate a black gap before the session_start() statement and your scripts will still run just fine, but the higher versions does not allow this.
So to answer your questions make sure that your scripts always starts like this.

before any other code, use the @ to suppress any warning, encase you have initiated it on a script that is linked to your current script.